# TensorFlow Checkpoints to S3

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am executing a Python-Tensorflow script on Amazon Sagemaker.  I need to checkpoint my model to the S3 instance I am using, but I can't find out how to do this without using the Sagemake Tensorflow version.

How does one checkpoint to an S3 instance without using the Sagemaker TF version?

Comment: Checkout [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto3)

Answer (score 0):

Create an object in S3 and enable versioning to the bucket. Everytime you change the model and save it to S3, it will be automatically versioned and stored in the bucket.

Hope it helps.